# Keeping pytest fixtures in one location and using them across submodules

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I am building a python package, using `pytest` for all unit testing. My package is composed of several modules, with various submodules under each module. The unit tests are within the `test` folder of each module (e.g., `./tumble/tumble/math/test/test_multiply.py` or `./tumble/tumble/science/test/test_divide.py`)

I have some fixtures that I want to share across all of the modules & submodules. Because of this, I want place them in a central location, `./tumble/tumble/test` in this example, and not have duplicate fixtures in each submodule (`math/test` and `science/test`).

If I place `conftest.py` within the `test` folder in each submodule, everything works as expected. However, I have the same fixtures in two locations, which isn't ideal.

When I place my fixtures in a central location, I am able to see them when I use the command `pytest --fixtures`, however, when I run `pytest`, it tells me `fixture not found` and the fixture is not listed in the `available fixtures`.

Do I need to move all of my unit tests under the `test` folder, or is there something that I can do to keep unit tests within the submodules, but fixtures in a central location?

```
tumble
+-- setup.py
+-- README.md
+-- tumble
|   +-- math
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- multiply.py
|   |   +-- test
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   |   +-- test
|   |   |   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   |   |   +-- test_multiply.py
|   +-- science
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- divide.py
|   |   +-- test
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   |   +-- test
|   |   |   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   |   |   +-- test_divide.py
|   +-- test
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- conftest.py
```

**multiply.py**

```
def multipy(x, y):
    return x * y
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def numbers():
    return (1, 5, 10)
```

**test_multiply.py**

```
import tumble
import pytest

assert tumble.multiply(numbers[0], numbers[1]) == 5
```

Comment: where did you put your "central" conftest.py file? i have one at the root folder of my project and any test running can see it (and run it's fixtures)

Comment: My "central" conftest.py is under `./tumble/tumble/test/conftest.py`

Comment: it should be directly under `/tumble` the root folder, as far as i understand pytest module. any branch not directly under your conftest, in this case `test_multiply.py` for example, can't "see" `numbers` fixtures

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from [pytest doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixture-functions) and [about plugins in pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-plugins) :

> Local conftest.py plugins contain directory-specific hook
>   implementations. Hook Session and test running activities will invoke
>   all hooks defined in conftest.py files closer to the root of the
>   filesystem

so, in order for your test to know the fixture, it should be higher in the hierarchy.
i.e. put your shared fixtures under the root folder, `/tumble/conftest.py`